# How do I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Codeplex?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, codeplex

I'd like to upload a project into codeplex, but I have no idea how.  I don't want to break my existing TFS + VS install.  Do I need to install anything special to work with Codeplex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Register on CodePlex
2. Create a project on CodePlex
3. Connect to your CodePlex project from Visual Studio
4. Add your existing project to the team project
5. Check-in